How can I fix my sliderstore() function to actually pass the data into google sheets?
<script>
    window.timer = 0;
    window.intervalId = null; // To hold the interval id for clearInterval

    function sliderstore(range1) {

      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var date = new Date();
      var time = date.toLocaleString();
      var dataset = [time, range1];
      sheet.appendRow(dataset);
      return dataset;
    }

    function range_disp1() {
        var range1 = document.getElementById("sensorvalue").value;
        var sens = document.getElementById("range_value1");
        sens.textContent = "Heat Sensor Value: " + range1 + " *K";
        google.script.run.sliderstore(range1);
    }

    function btnstartstop() {
        var buttonValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("btn1").value);
        var paragraph = document.getElementById("rec");
        var timp = document.getElementById("time");

        if (buttonValue === 1) {

            // Start Recording
            paragraph.textContent = "Stop Recording";
            window.intervalId = setInterval(function() {
                //increase time +1 s every Second
                timer++;
                timp.textContent = "Timer: " + timer + " s";

            }, 1000); // Update timer every second (1000 ms)
        } else {
            // Stop Recording
            paragraph.textContent = "Start Recording";
            clearInterval(window.intervalId);
            timer = 0; // Reset timer
            timp.textContent = "Timer: 0 s";
        }

        // Toggle buttonValue between 1 and 0
        document.getElementById("btn1").value = (buttonValue === 1) ? 0 : 1;
    }

</script>

I have been stuck on this for 2 days now, I expected it to rerun the function with every time the function for displaying the range would be ran on every click as per onclick="" in HTML. So far it doesn't even pass anything onto google sheets. sliderstore() function works on itself but when I try to integrate it it just doesn't want to do anything it seems. what am I missing?
This is all in google script as well within the google sheets extension's.

It's impossible to call Spreadsheet Service (Class SpreadsheetApp) methods directly from client-side code. The server-side function might be called from the client side using google.script.run. For further details, please read

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices

